# How to use while loop in Servlet Chaining

Tags: java, servlets

There are some steps

1. In first step I have computed some values in first servlet (consider it as `Project 1`) and passing to second servlet (consider it as another `Project 2`).
2. From second servlet (consider it as `project 2` ) passing the values again to third servlet (consider it as `Project 1`).
3. From third servlet(consider it as `Project 1`) passing the values to fourth servlet (consider it as `project 2` ).

The steps 1 to 3 should run for `t` (might be 10) times in sequence.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass request arguments between servlets using request dispatcher class with forward method. With forward method, everything happens in the server side and the user only sees the final output. You can otherwise repeatedly send the redirect requests back to the browser. if you choose this option, every request will be a brand new request and hence passing arguments between servlets might be tricky. You can use a session variable or something.

Why would you want to do this exactly? Have you considered other more efficient solutions?

Comment: because i am using probabilistic method so based on t trials only i can come to conclusion thats why. Thanks.